# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshContentEditable' of undefined

Tags: javascript, wordpress

We have multisite with latest wordpress version 5.2.2
I have a latest plugin 'PDF viewer for WordPress' 7.5

Right now I get below error, when I was click on "ok" button of, pdf popup

[image]

[image]

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'refreshContentEditable' of undefined

In this file  ../wp-includes/js/tinymce/wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515

```
at wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1
at Wp (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at zw.focus (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at lp.execCommand (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at zw.execCommand (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at zw.insertContent (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at i.onsubmit (tnc-pdf-button.js?wp-mce-4940-20190515:365)
at dp.c.fire (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at i.fire (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
at i.fire (wp-tinymce.js?ver=4940-20190515:1)
```

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasClass' of undefined
```

In this file   ../wp-includes/js/wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.2

```
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (wp-auth-check.min.js?ver=5.2.2:1)
at HTMLDocument.dispatch (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:3)
at HTMLDocument.r.handle (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:3)
at Object.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:3)
at Object.a.event.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:8)
at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:3)
at Function.each (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:2)
at a.fn.init.each (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:2)
at a.fn.init.trigger (load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,underscore,moxiejs,plupload&ver=5.2.2:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (heartbeat.min.js?ver=5.2.2:1)
```

Comment: Can you add a link to the plugin to your question? I can't find that exact one. Anyway, did you check that the plugin is compatible with the latest version of WP?

Comment: thanks @ChrisG, Yes plugin is compatible with our WP version.

Comment: So.... can you add the link?

Comment: https://codecanyon.net/item/pdf-viewer-for-wordpress/8182815?_ga=2.197751468.2011622817.1564649797-1163843881.1564572110

Actually we have paid version of this plugin. but we just expire the pad support.

Comment: Yes one more thing fyi : we have multisite

Comment: I don't think we can help you with this. Try the plugin in a fresh, empty Wordpress installation and see if the error persists. Try narrowing it down.

Comment: ok, thanks @ChrisG, for your support

Answer (score 1):

I have sort out it, one of the plugin WP-tree was create conflict ion, as I have deactivate it, pdf can work fine